# Some problems when referring a ListView

Tags: android, listview

Hey guys I was trying to create an app that creates some data in the MainActivity and then store it to an array and pass it to another activity, I created another activity (in which contains a ListView) so that users can review the data, but whenever I refer that ListView in the second activity's java file, the Intent stops working and the app stops responding. Here is the code I found in my app that causes the error:

```
ListView codeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.code_list);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, code_array);

codeList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And here is the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmMLp.jpg

and these are the error logs code that I got in logcat:

```
09-07 10:18:10.191  12852-12852/com.plufinity.steven.codey E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.plufinity.steven.codey, PID: 12852
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
```

Comment: Seems like your `code_array` contains nulls.

Comment: oh really? but I thought I added a value to it, let me try then :)

Comment: oh seems like you're right laalto :) the arrays did contain nulls, thanks a lot for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

An NPE like this in `ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource()` occurs when the adapter tries to invoke `toString()` on an object in the array you passed to the adapter. Make sure the array does not contain any `null` values in it.